# Faster way to do _mm256_set1_ps

Tags: x86-64, avx2

Is there a faster way to do _mm256_set1_ps in assembly than the C intrinsic? It appears that the intrinsic compiles down to a sequence of vmovss, vshufps, vmovss, vshufps and vinsertf128, which even the intrinsics guide itself says is inefficient. I am wondering if there are alternative ways to do this. I realize that if there is Intel probably has implemented it, but doesn't hurt to ask....

Comment: What value do you want to set? A constant, a value from memory, from another register? How did you compile (did you use `-march=native -O2`, or something similar)? There is [`VBROADCASTSS `](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vbroadcast) which I assume is the most efficient way for non-constant values.

Comment: @chtz: a good compiler will typically use `vbroadcastss` to implement `_mm256_set1_ps`, especially if it's a run-time variable that's coming from memory like `array[i]` or something.  Some compilers are silly and expand a scalar constant to a vector constant at compile time, even if they end up just loading it into a register once ahead of a loop, not using it as a memory source operand.  This saves 1 byte of code size for `vmovaps` vs. `vbroadcastss`, but costs 32 bytes of data cache footprint instead of 4.  (AVX CPUs implement broadcast loads right in the load port, at least Intel does.)

Answer (score 1):

While this has been partially addressed for some time, I found it as part of dealing with some similar issues and thought a formal answer might be of interest. I'm aware of two main cases.

1. The constant for `_mm256_set1_ps()` is in memory at a known address. As @Peter Cordes mentioned above in the comments, AVX `vbroadcastss` applies in this case.
2. The constant is already in the low bits of a register. AVX2 `vbroadcastss` is suitable here (AVX requires `vpermilps` to set the lower 128 bits followed by `vperm2f128` to set the upper 128, I believe).

I've encountered inefficient code generation around this for a variety of reasons and have implemented my own variants of `_mm_set1_ps()` and `_mm256_set1_ps()` to encourage more efficient compilation. Don't feel I'm in a position to make more specific recommendations than checking the disassembly you're getting, however.

Comment: This is tagged AVX2; that means `vbroadcastss ymm, xmm` is available for the already-in-register case.  (AVX1 only provides the memory-source version.)  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vbroadcast.  If your compiler doesn't do that, make sure to enable optimization and `-march=znver1` or `-march=haswell` (or MSVC `-arch:AVX2`), and if that doesn't work then upgrade to the latest clang or GCC.

Comment: Thanks Peter, noted. (Updating clang or gcc won't be helpful when coding in languages other than C/C++, though.)

Comment: You probably won't be using **C** intrinsics if it's not C or C++ (or Objective-C).  Many other languages use the same GCC or LLVM back-end optimizer, although many of those don't use C intrinsics either, such as Rust which has its own style of intrinsics with similar names I think.

Comment: Hi Peter, I think we're approaching uninteresting hairsplitting but most discussion I encounter uses Intel's intrinsic and instruction names interchangeably regardless of programming language or compiler. I don't know of intrinsic specific surveys but language level data suggests C and C++ might not be the majority use case. Since the OP didn't put a language tag I chose to not to make assumptions.

Comment: Yeah we're getting off topic here, but now I'm curious.  Are there other mainstream languages with SIMD intrinsics that use names like `_mm_add_epi32`?  Or are you just saying that developers talk about intrinsics that way even if they're using languages like C# where intrinsics look like [`Sse2.add`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.sse2.add?view=net-6.0)?  Hmm, the docs do mention the C intrinsic name `_mm_add_epi8` as well as the shorter and simpler `paddb`. I always just think in terms of asm mnemonic, because that's what tables of uops/latency use.

Comment: The latter. My experience is pretty much everybody interested in x64 performance this level ends up spending enough time with the Intel Intrinsics Guide to be well exposed to both Intel instrinsics and instruction naming. .NET naming conventions do provide some isolation but it's not like you're going to do blends, permutes, or quite a few other operations without the Intrinsics Guide. I would also say this question is hello world level when checking Fortran vectorization disassembly (probably not OP intent but question readers often have different contexts than OPs).

Comment: When I'm talking about what operations some code does, e.g. in comments on SO, I usually use asm mnemonics.  Only C intrinsic names if it's actually a C or C++ question using them, and even then the asm mnemonics are shorter to type and quicker to read, and if you're checking compiler output and instruction tables, that's a form you need to be familiar with anyway.  I only look at the intrinsics guide when I want to map asm to that style of intrinsics.  But maybe that's just me and some other folks that like to get into CPU-architecture details and regularly consult https://uops.info/

Comment: Especially for AVX-512, I find the intrinsics guide is nearly-unusably bloated (with mask/maskz in all 3 sizes) vs. an asm instruction reference like https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ scraped from Intel's vol.2 manual when I'm looking for available operations that I remember existing.  And Intel's asm manual entries do list C intrinsic names.  But anyway, thanks for the insight on how some groups of people talk about instructions / intrinsics.